# Display results then give option to export to .csv?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a table on my site that is generated using PHP and a mysql DB. I would like to have the table displayed with an option below to export the results to a .csv file.

I was trying to setup a button/link at the bottom that would run the below php file.
However it just exports the entire HTML code into the .csv file ... could someone help me out ?

I run the query then -->

```
$num_fields = $result->field_count;

$headers = array();

 // Creating headers for output files
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
{
    $headers[] = $result->fetch_fields();
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result)
{
 // name of file with date
    $filename = "AccessReport-".date('Y-m-d').".csv";

        // Setting header types for csv file.
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
             fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

 }
 $result->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create a new action in the controller to download CSV for example

```
public function csvAction() {

        $year = $this->_getParam('year');
        $month = $this->_getParam('month');
        $week = $this->_getParam('week');

        $arrCsvOutputCols = array();
        $title = '';

        if ($year && $month && $week) {
            $models = $this->db()->fetchAll("
            SELECT 
                YEAR(`create_date`) AS `year`,
                MONTH(`create_date`) AS `month`, 
                WEEK(`create_date`) AS `week`, 
                DAY(`create_date`) AS `day`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` < 21 then 1 else 0 end) `a`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 21 AND `age` < 31 then 1 else 0 end) `b`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 31 AND `age` < 41 then 1 else 0 end) `c`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 41 AND `age` < 51 then 1 else 0 end) `d`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 51 AND `age` < 61 then 1 else 0 end) `e`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 61 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `f`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 71 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `g`,
                SUM(case WHEN `age` > 80 then 1 else 0 end) `h`
            FROM 
                dtb_member 
            GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `week`,`day` HAVING `year` = ? AND `month` = ? AND `week` = ?
            ORDER BY `day` ASC;"
            , array($year, $month, $week));
            array_push($arrCsvOutputCols,'year','month','week','day');
            $title = '"Year","Month","Week","Day",';
        } elseif ($year && $month) {
            $models = $this->db()->fetchAll("
                SELECT 
                    YEAR(`create_date`) AS `year`, 
                    MONTH(`create_date`) AS `month`, 
                    WEEK(`create_date`) AS `week`, 
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` < 21 then 1 else 0 end) `a`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 21 AND `age` < 31 then 1 else 0 end) `b`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 31 AND `age` < 41 then 1 else 0 end) `c`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 41 AND `age` < 51 then 1 else 0 end) `d`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 51 AND `age` < 61 then 1 else 0 end) `e`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 61 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `f`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 71 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `g`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` > 80 then 1 else 0 end) `h`
                FROM 
                    dtb_member 
                GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `week` HAVING `year` = ? AND `month` = ? 
                ORDER BY `week` ASC;"
            , array($year, $month));
            array_push($arrCsvOutputCols,'year','month','week');
            $title = '"Year","Month","Week",';
        } elseif ($year) {
            $models = $blood = $this->db()->fetchAll("
                SELECT 
                    YEAR(`create_date`) AS `year`, 
                    MONTH(`create_date`) AS `month`, 
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` < 21 then 1 else 0 end) `a`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 21 AND `age` < 31 then 1 else 0 end) `b`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 31 AND `age` < 41 then 1 else 0 end) `c`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 41 AND `age` < 51 then 1 else 0 end) `d`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 51 AND `age` < 61 then 1 else 0 end) `e`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 61 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `f`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 71 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `g`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` > 80 then 1 else 0 end) `h`
                FROM 
                    dtb_member 
                GROUP BY `year`, `month` HAVING `year` = ? 
                ORDER BY `month` ASC;"
            , $year);
            array_push($arrCsvOutputCols,'year','month');
            $title = '"Year","Month",';
        } else {
            $models = $this->db()->fetchAll("
                SELECT 
                    YEAR(`create_date`) AS `year`, 
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` < 21 then 1 else 0 end) `a`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 21 AND `age` < 31 then 1 else 0 end) `b`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 31 AND `age` < 41 then 1 else 0 end) `c`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 41 AND `age` < 51 then 1 else 0 end) `d`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 51 AND `age` < 61 then 1 else 0 end) `e`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 61 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `f`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` >= 71 AND `age` < 71 then 1 else 0 end) `g`,
                    SUM(case WHEN `age` > 80 then 1 else 0 end) `h`
                FROM 
                    dtb_member 
                GROUP BY `year` HAVING `year` > 0 
                ORDER BY `year` ASC;"
            );
            array_push($arrCsvOutputCols,'year');
            $title = '"Year",';
        }

        ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        if (preg_match("/MSIE 8\.0/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            header('Content-Disposition: filename=age_' . time() . '.csv');
        } else {
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=age_' . time() . '.csv');
        }
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-control: public');
        array_push($arrCsvOutputCols,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
        $arrCsvOutputTitle = $title.'"0-20","21-30","31-40","41-50","51-60","61-70","71-80","81-"';

        echo mb_convert_encoding($arrCsvOutputTitle, 'SJIS-win', 'UTF-8') . "\r\n";

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $item = $model;
            $cols = array();

            foreach ($arrCsvOutputCols as $col) {
                if ($col) {
                    $value = $item[$col];
                    $value = str_replace("\r", "", $value);
                    $value = str_replace("\n", "", $value);
                    $value = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $value);

                        array_push($cols, '"' . $value . '"');

                } else {   

                array_push($cols, '');
                } 
            }
            echo mb_convert_encoding(join(",", $cols), 'SJIS-win', 'UTF-8') . "\r\n";
        }

    }
```